# my apache is not starting and its giving me error

Tags: apache

i tried starting my apache is was showing me this

> [Fri Jan 22 06:50:10.323206 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2208:tid 516]
>   AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an
>   ID which matches the server name [Fri Jan 22 06:50:10.885705 2016]
>   [ssl:warn] [pid 2208:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server
>   certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Fri
>   Jan 22 06:50:12.854457 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2208:tid 516]
>   AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15 configured --
>   resuming normal operations [Fri Jan 22 06:50:12.854457 2016]
>   [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2208:tid 516] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11
>   Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13 [Fri Jan 22 06:50:12.854457 2016]
>   [core:notice] [pid 2208:tid 516] AH00094: Command line:
>   'C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache' [Fri Jan 22
>   06:50:12.932580 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2208:tid 516] AH00418:
>   Parent: Created child process 4136 [Fri Jan 22 06:50:14.291952 2016]
>   [ssl:warn] [pid 4136:tid 524] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server
>   certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Fri
>   Jan 22 06:50:14.573174 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4136:tid 524] AH01909:
>   www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which
>   matches the server name [Fri Jan 22 06:50:14.916956 2016]
>   [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4136:tid 524] AH00354: Child: Starting 150
>   worker threads. "

Comment: this question is too broad, and your not even asking a question

Comment: open <apache home>/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf  and change the server name of line bellow by the common name of your cert*
before: 
httpd-ssl.conf:ServerName www.example.com:443

after :
httpd-ssl.conf:ServerName my_certificat_common_name:443

Answer (score 0):

You're indicating in your vhost `www.example.com` to use a ssl certificate that's not valid.

Two ways to tackle this issue:

- give him a valid certificate
- remove the certificate "link" from your ghost configuration

Without more details, however, is difficult to help you in a more concrete way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the common name of the certificate which is binded to the domain in its virtual host. Please run the below command to check the content of the certificate

openssl x509 -inform pem -in cerfile.cer -noout -text

If the common name is not matching with the domain , then please replace it with the certificate whose common matches and is having a valid private key .

However, in some cases the private key does not match with the certificate and hence Apache throws this error. In this situation please get the certificate reissues with the CA by sharing a new CSR with them